# how to fetch N row chunk in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

i am trying to fetch n row from Cassandra using java-driver. but i not able to fetch first n row means 10 row then again next 10 row from 11th row. if any one have idea give suggestion. i already try by setfetchsize and set pagestatus blahh

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your source code that doesn't work as want. Do you get an error message?

Comment: i want to fetch N row then from N+1 to again N row like 4 row in my table first 2 row ->>>row1 ,row2 store resultset and print then again execute same query and fetch 3rd row and 4row. i try to used by setfetchsize but that not working int RESULTS_PER_PAGE =2; 
  Statement st = new SimpleStatement("select * from mdb");
  st.setFetchSize(RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
 
 
     ResultSet result=session.execute(st);
  for (Row row : result) {
   int name_var = row.getInt("name");
   int roll_var = row.getInt("roll");
 }    its printing all 4 row but i want only 2 row here then next time 2

Answer (score 0):

This page in the documentation covers it: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/2.1/features/paging

Comment: dear Olivier thank for reply  I set RESULTS_PER_PAGE =4 but my for loop of row:resultset giving full data but i want only 4 data then next time again in different resultset 4 data from last 5th row code given below RESULTS_PER_PAGE =4; 
  Statement st = new SimpleStatement("select * from mdb");
  st.setFetchSize(RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
 
 
     ResultSet result=session.execute(st);
  for (Row row : result) {
   int name_var = row.getInt("name");
   int roll_var = row.getInt("roll");
  
   System.out.println("roll_var="+roll_var+"name_var="+name_var);
  }

Comment: Read the page I linked to, the code examples show how to do this.

Comment: yeah Olivier i have gone through this, but  ResultSet result giving fully row instead of 4 row as code mention in above comment. could you please send a example link. this paging is not working in java driver.

Comment: Did you use `ResultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching()` to avoid going past the first page?